# Object [object Object] has no method 'cleditor'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cleditor

I am unable to make CLEditor work for me. Please find the scipt files being adding in _Layout.cshtml

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.cleditor.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cleditor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.cleditor.min.js")" type="text/javascript"  ></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Html.Telerik().StyleSheetRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.css").Add("telerik.vista.css"));
```

Partial View has given below code.

```
<textarea id="input" name="input"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#input").cleditor();
</script>
```

This is happing in all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Per their site, "It is recommended that you install these files into a folder called cleditor with a subfolder called images."

I placed the folder in Scripts and then used this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css")" />    
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.min.js")"></script>
```